# .NET MVC: Finding default Bootsrap JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In an out-of-the-box implementation of an MVC app using Bootstrap in Visual Studio 2013, there seems to be some javasvript that works on this element:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                ....
</li>
```

When that element is clicked, there is, somewhere, some JavaScript that changes the class in this element to:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown open">
                ....
</li>
```

I want to augment/alter whatever script this is, but I can't find it.  Or, I could also just create my own that works along side the existing script, but I can't figure out how to reference this element when it doesn't have an id.  I'd rather not add my own id, as this list of li's is generated dynamically and I don't want to deal with referencing all the id's in the JavaScript.

How would I find the existing script that is making this change?  OR How would I create my own script to handle the on-click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the open `li` using `css class selector` '.':

```
$(".dropdown.open")
```

this will give you the currently open dropdown.

Explanation:

'CSS selectors' allow you to select elements using CSS syntax.  For example:

'#id' where the '#' indicates the following text is the `id` of the element.
'.class' allows you to select all elements by class, eg `$(".dropdown")` gives you all elements with class "dropdown".  These can be combined `".dropdown.open"` - all elements with both class dropdown and open

Never change the library directly, there's an event you can hook into:

```
$('#id_of_ul').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something...
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Explanation:

`.on` is the jquery event hook to provide your own handler when something happens, eg: `$("#id").on('click', function...`.

In this case, the event is called `shown.bs.dropdown` and is provided / raised by the `twitter-bootstrap dropdown` functionality.

To answer the explicit question of where to find the scripts, you can download from getbootstrap.com or, they'll be in your MVC project under `Scripts\`

Comment: Ok, thanks freedom.  This gives me some things to digest.  A couple of questions.  In your first statement about $(".dropdown.open")... I assume you are saying I could reference this in CSS?  But your syntax seems to be JavaScript.

Comment: Not CSS, css selectors.  Edited answer.

Comment: Ok, css selectors is a new concept for me.  Am I understanding correctly that in JabaScript, I can reference an element by the elements in the CSS class, and not an ID?  And if so, how would I create a function that handles the on-click event?  Or would I use ''shown.bs.dropdown''?

Comment: In this case, use the provided event. You don't need to worry about css selectors for your question, it was to answer the bit in the middle 'how to do I select this without an ID'.

Comment: ok, understood.  And... I posted a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848518/net-mvc-bootstrap-shown-bs-dropdown-not-working

Comment: Bonus for adding a new question :)