# .NET MVC Bootstrap: shown.bs.dropdown Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to tap into the 'shown.bs.dropdown' event on the ul with the id of 'navul'. Can't seem to get it working.  Here's my script:

```
<script>
    $('#navul').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        alert('hello');
    })
</script>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="navul" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="/Content/images/IconsNav/nav_appts.png" style="padding: 0px 5px 3px 0px;">Appointments<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("YourAppointments", "YourAppointments", "Appointments")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule Appointment", "ScheduleAppointment", "Appointments")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I never get the alert.  What am I doing wrong? I'm working off this:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% up with twitter-bootstrap - try one of the higher element IDs, eg ".navbar"

Comment: Tried that.  I added an id to the first div, and changed the javascript to match.  No luck.  Then the second div.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `.on` event will only register the event if the element already exists when `.on` is called, if your script is too soon, it won't register, try loading in the jquery document ready, ie:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.navbar').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
            alert('hello');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm.  Seems like a solid idea, but still not working.  I found this working example.  I'll see if I can replicate it, and then modify it to meet my needs.  http://www.bootply.com/114783

Comment: I went to the getbootstrap page, opened console (F12), entered `$(".navbar").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function() { alert("x"); })` then went to the "within a navbar" example on the page and clicked on Dropdown[v] - it gave the alert.

Comment: yeah, there seems to be something else wrong with my page.  I can't get any JavaScript to work. Gota spend some time in Fiddler seeing what's wrong.